# How Develop Win32 and DirectX in VSCode

Tags: windows, directx, visual-studio-code

I want develop Win32 and DirectX in Visual Studio Code.

I already installed gcc, mingw.

OS is windows10.

How do I setting it?

Comment: mingw directx headers are not official and are sometimes out of date (sometimes years behind) in comparison with Windows SDK.

Comment: If you plan to ever debug your DirectX code you should consider getting Visual Studio instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Microsoft Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) for details on developing C++ code with VS Code.

The latest DirectX headers and link libraries are found in the Windows 10 SDK. Using the Visual C++ or clang/LLVM for Windows toolsets are the best options for consuming the latest Windows 10 SDK.

> You may find the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki) a useful starting point, although my tutorials focus on the Visual Studio MSBuild build environment. I also reference using CMake. You can use MSBuild through Visual Studio Community, and you can use CMake through either VS Community or [VS Code](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-tools-extension-for-visual-studio-code/).